# css li's and floats - basically a grid

Tags: css

Basically a product grid, which should be floated left.
Occasionally the last item is not floating left, why ?

Example here
http://bartels-sondermaschinenbau.de/Regale/Fachbodenregale-Lager/Stecksystem/
and here
http://bartels-sondermaschinenbau.de/Regalbau/

There is some js which is equalizing the box heights, which may be breaking things?

Somethings wrong, but i can't spot it.
It does not happen everywhere either, just to make it confusing
Example - where all ok
http://bartels-sondermaschinenbau.de/Werkstatt/Hallen-Aussenanlage/Material-Lagercontainer/

Comment: A product grid could be considered _tabular data._ I smell a legitimate use for a table here.

Comment: in what browsers do you see the issue? Looks fine in Chrome **unless I change the zoom**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't work in FF 17.0.1 too. Add `height: 201px` to `li` without `oxEqualized` class.

Comment: ok - not sure this is ideal, but going for this at the moment as it seems to solve the problem easily.

Comment: i had accepted this, but it seems it not true. Here for example in chrome and firefox, the same problem, even with no js for the height. Ahh i forgot to change the height to 201. - seems to be working!

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine.

It looks like you have a zoom in your text, as pointed out by @lnrbob.

Press CTRL + 0 in Firefox, or follow View Menu in every browser and set zoom to 0, and retry...